Why doesn't the Text Composable fit the size that the text occupies?
I have this code, in MessageItem is the Surface and also inside that Surface is the Text.
I tried with .wrapContentSize() but it didn't work
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ChatScreen(
    chatId: String?,
    onBack: () -> Unit
) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Chat with Alice"
                    )
                }
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            SendMessageBox()
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        ListOfMessages(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
    }
}

@Composable
fun ListOfMessages(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        items(getFakeMessages()) { message ->
            MessageItem(message)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MessageItem(message: Message) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .then(if (message.isMine) Modifier.padding(start = 48.dp) else Modifier),
        horizontalArrangement = if (message.isMine) Arrangement.End else Arrangement.Start
    ) {
        if (!message.isMine) {
            Avatar(
                imageUrl = message.senderAvatar,
                size = 40.dp,
                contentDescription = "${message.senderName}'s avatar"
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        }
        Column {
            if (message.isMine) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            } else {
                Text(
                    text = message.senderName,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            }
            when (val content = message.messageContent) {
                is MessageContent.TextMessage -> {
                    Surface(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                        color = if (message.isMine) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = content.message,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                            color = if (message.isMine) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary else Color.White
                        )
                    }
                }

                is MessageContent.ImageMessage -> {
                    AsyncImage(
                        model = content.imageUrl,
                        contentDescription = content.contentDescription,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(40.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                    )
                }
            }
            Text(
                text = message.timestamp,
                fontSize = 12.sp
            )
        }
    }
}


Any idea what I'm doing wrong and why the Surface doesn't fit the size of the text?

Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark button at the left side of an answer. Thank you!

This is a bug / not supported feature that is present since the beginnings of Jetpack Compose, as described in Issue #206039942 on the Google Issue Tracker.
There is a suggested workaround that you can use. The Text Composable has a onTextLayout callback which returns a TextLayoutResult. The TextLayoutResult holds information about the coordinates of each individual line displayed in the Text Composable.
By then applying a layout Modifier, you can alter the size of the Text Composable to match the measured width of the longest line inside of the Text Composable.
You can create a WrappingText Composable like this:
@Composable
fun WrappingText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    minLines: Int = 1,
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current

) {
    var textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
    Text(
        text = text,
        modifier = modifier
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                val newTextLayoutResult = textLayoutResult!!

                if (newTextLayoutResult.lineCount == 0) {
                    // Default behavior if there is no text
                    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                        placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                    }
                } else {
                    // get coordinate of line which goes the furthest to the left
                    val minX = (0 until newTextLayoutResult.lineCount).minOf(newTextLayoutResult::getLineLeft)
                    // get coordinate of line which goes the furthest to the right
                    val maxX = (0 until newTextLayoutResult.lineCount).maxOf(newTextLayoutResult::getLineRight)
                    // set width to match longest line
                    layout(ceil(maxX - minX).toInt(), placeable.height) {
                        placeable.placeRelative(-floor(minX).toInt(), 0)
                    }
                }
            },
        onTextLayout = {
            textLayoutResult = it
        },
        color = color,
        fontSize = fontSize,
        fontStyle = fontStyle,
        fontWeight = fontWeight,
        fontFamily = fontFamily,
        letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
        textDecoration = textDecoration,
        textAlign = textAlign,
        lineHeight = lineHeight,
        overflow = overflow,
        softWrap = softWrap,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        minLines = minLines,
        style = style
    )
}

Then, use it in your MessageItem Composable like this:
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
) {
    WrappingText(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .wrapContentSize(),
        text = "Are you going to that Kotlin conference to Colorado next week, my dear friend?",
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
        textAlign = TextAlign.End
    )
}

Output:

